# Getting number of Category's in a guild discord.js V13

Tags: discord.js

For my bot I am making a server info command, currently I can't seem to get the number of category's in a guild so when a user runs `!serverinfo` there is an embed and under **Categorys** will display a number. Currently the number that is displayed is 0. How do I fix this?

**Code**

```js
 const channels = message.guild.channels.cache;

  const embed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setAuthor(message.guild.name, message.guild.iconURL({dynamic: true}))
  .setThumbnail(message.guild.iconURL({dynaic: true}))
  .addField(`Owner`, `${owner.user.tag}`,true)
  .addField(`Categorys`, `${channels.filter(channel => channel.type === "category").size}`,true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the amount of categories with

```js
message.guild.channels.cache.filter(ch => ch.type === 'GUILD_CATEGORY').size
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by fetching all the channels (to cache them all) and then filter the categories.

```js
message.guild.channels.fetch().then(channels => {
  console.log(channels.filter(c => c.type === "GUILD_CATEGORY").size)
})
```

Related docs:
[`GuildChannelManager.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch)
[`Channel.type`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Channel?scrollTo=type)